# JSON api response from the linkedin

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Using the below URL I have got the profile response from linkedin in the form of XML.

```
this.http.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token='+token,{headers: headers})
```

How can I get the response in JSON format? I have tried with the URL but I'm getting the error.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json~?oauth2_access_token=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format` should be sent as query parameter:

Try:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json&oauth2_access_token=xxxx
```